# Ler todos os arquivos txt em uma pasta

Tags: java

Estou tentando listar em meu projeto todos os arquivos que salvei anteriormente no programa dentro da pasta de consultas, porem ele nao mostra somente os arquivos, esta mostrando também os seus respectivos caminhos. Como faço pra deixar essa função mais organizada somente com os nome dos arquivos txt e quem sabe ate um método para buscar por nome?

```
File arquivo; 
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dhyego\\Dropbox\\Projeto Software\\Main\\Consultas")).forEach(filePath -> {
if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
    System.out.println(filePath);
}
```

saida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual versão do java você tá usando?

Comment: @adelmo00 Provavelmente Java8, não foi nessa versão que implementaram as expressões lambda?

Comment: Foi nessa sim. Ia responder, mas o @jbueno já o fez e espero que te ajude. Não percebi a expressão lambda no final da linha.

Comment: estou usando a Versão 8

Comment: @CarlosDiego você alterou completamente a pergunta, colocando outra dúvida, e a pergunta já foi respondida. Vou retornar pra duvida original, sempre que tiver uma nova duvida, nao altere a pergunta, aceite a resposta da atual e abra uma nova.

Comment: @CarlosDiego Mantenha a pergunta como estava antes e abra uma nova com sua nova dúvida. Dessa forma você vai acabar invalidando a minha resposta.

Comment: feito jbueno > http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136281/abrir-arquivo-txt-dentro-de-uma-pasta-e-editar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-arquivo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simples, usando o método [**`getFileName`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName()) de `Path`.

Como o `Files.Walk` retorna uma coleção de `Path's`, logo o objeto `filePath` dentro do `forEach` é uma instância de `Path`.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dhyego\\Dropbox\\Projeto Software\\Main\\Consultas")).forEach(filePath -> {
    if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
        System.out.println(filePath.getFileName().toString());
    }
});
```