# Listagem de arquivos de uma pasta

Tags: java

Olá
Estou usando o JFileChooser para pegar arquivos no sistema.

Só que agora preciso usar o JFileChooser para selecionar pastas e adicionar todo o seu conteúdo no programa. Usei o `DIRECTORIES_ONLY` e deu certo. Agora eu quero adicionar todos os arquivos (mediante um filto de tipo de arquivo (mp3)) num arrayList e mostrar para o usuário. Porém já rodei boa parte da internet e os códigos que encontro como base não servem/não funcionam. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Preciso utilizar JFileChooser, não .walk

Atualmente, eu estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
adicionarPasta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY); 
            String diretorio = chooser.getAbsolutePath();//essa linha está com erro
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File file = new File(diretorio);
            File afile[] = file.listFiles();
            int i = 0;
            for (int j = afile.length; i < j; i++) {
                File arquivos = afile[i];
                System.out.println(arquivos.getName());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ler todos os arquivos txt em uma pasta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136268/ler-todos-os-arquivos-txt-em-uma-pasta)

Answer (score 1):

**Usando Java 8**

Caso queira retornar os objetos `File`:

```
private ArrayList<File> listar(String caminho, String extensao) {
  File pasta = new File(caminho);

  return this.listar(pasta, extensao);
}

private ArrayList<File> listar(File pasta, String extensao) {
  ArrayList<File> arquivos;

  arquivos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(pasta.listFiles()));
  arquivos.removeIf(arquivo -> !arquivo.getName().endsWith(extensao));

  return arquivos;
}
```

O uso seria o seguinte:

```
final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

System.out.println(this.listar(chooser.getSelectedFile(), ".mp3"));
```

Comment: A pessoa que deu downvote pode dizer o que está errado pra que eu possa corrigir a resposta?

Answer (score 0):

O método [getSelectedFiles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFiles()) de [javax.swing.JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) retorna um File[]. Você pode utilizá-lo para retornar um array de File objects, após habilitar seleção múltipla com [setMultiSelectionEnabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled%28boolean%29). Se não habilitar seleção múltipla, não poderá selecionar vários arquivos de uma vez, e retornar todos com o getSelectecdFiles.

Comment: Pois é, mas eu não quero que o usuário adicione mais de um arquivo de forma manual. O que eu quero é um "adicionar pasta completa" com arquivos .mp3 à um arraylist de file

Comment: Você pode usar o [new File("folder/path").listFiles()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) :p Ele também retorna um File[]. É só pegar o caminho da pasta selecionado com o JFileChooser, e iterar sobre o listFiles() para passá-los para um ArrayList ou whatever.